# How to use Trac like JIRA

Tags: bug-tracking

I have been using JIRA for the past 15 months, and now I find myself on a project that is using Trac.  How do I look up a ticket just by the ticket number in Trac?  I am use to just typing the ticket value in the upper right hand side of JIRA and it finding that one ticket.  I tried the same thing in Trac and was not so lucky.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can't you just put it on the URL?

Alternatively, search for the ticket - put a # in front of the ticket number and you're good to go. Other [options are available](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracSearch) too:

> For quick access to various project
>   resources, the quick-search field at
>   the top of every page can be used to
>   enter a wiki link, which will take you
>   directly to the resource identified by
>   that link.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> * [42] -- Opens change set 42
> * #42 -- Opens ticket number 42
> * {1} -- Opens report 1
> * /trunk -- Opens the browser for the trunk directory
> ```

eg. http://trac.edgewall.org/ticket/8199